# Java Leftmost Binary Search

Tags: java, arrays, search, integer, binary-search

I am trying to modify a Recursive Binary Search function so that it will find the leftmost index of the element given the array contains multiples of that element.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class LeftmostBinarySearch {

    private static int myBinarySearch(int key, int[] a, int lo, int hi) {
    if (lo > hi) {
        return -1;
    }
    int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
    if (key < a[mid]) {
        return myBinarySearch(key, a, lo, mid - 1);
    } else if (key > a[mid]) {
        return myBinarySearch(key, a, mid + 1, hi);
    } else {
        return mid;
    }
}

    public static int myBinarySearch(int key, int[] a) {
    return myBinarySearch(key, a, 0, a.length - 1);
}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String fileName = args[0] + ".txt";
        System.out.println(fileName);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        int[] data = new int[7];
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            data[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            i++;
        }
        Arrays.sort(data);
        System.out.format("%2s%2s%2s%2s%2s%2s%2s%2s%2s%2s%2s%2s%2s", " 0",
                "  ", " 1", "  ", " 2", "  ", " 3", "  ", " 4", "  ", " 5", "  ", " 6\n");
        System.out.format("%2s%2s%2s%2s%2s%2s%2s%2s%2s%2s%2s%2s%2s", data[j],
                "  ", data[j + 1], "  ", data[j + 2], "  ", data[j + 3], "  ",
                data[j + 4], " ", data[j + 5], "  ", data[j + 6] + "\n");

        int input = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

        while ((Integer) input != null) {
            int key = input;
            System.out.println(data[0]);
            if (myBinarySearch(key, data) != -1) {
                System.out.println(input + " found: "
                        + myBinarySearch(key, data));
            }
            input = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

The output I have gotten from this is:

```
C:\Users\Shirley\algs4>java LeftmostBinarySearch mydata
 0   1   2   3   4   5   6
10  20  20  30  40  40  40
10
10 found: 0
20
20 found: 1
30
30 found: 3
40
40 found: 5
```

I have tried changing how I calculate mid to (hi + lo - 1)/2 and it works for 40, gives index 3, but for 20 it gives index 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the last line:

```
else return mid;
```

Your list contains duplicates so mid may not be the leftmost match. So try:

```
else {
  while(--mid>=0) {
    if (a[mid]!=key) break;
  }
  return mid+1;
}
```

Comment: That did it. I wasn't thinking about doing it at the end. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to check `if(key == a[mid])`. If it is equal, you need to check if the last element in left portion is same until you find a different element.

The following check should come before you branch left or right

```
if (key == a[mid]) {
    while (--mid >= 0) {
        if (key != a[mid]) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return ++mid;
}
```

Comment: this however is introducing yet another pair of decision blocks and loop and adding to the algorithm's complexity, is there optimized way to do this using the 'standard' implementation or one should use Hermann Bottenbruch's alternative procedure -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Alternative_procedure